# In MATLAB, why does delaunayTriangulation give different number of triangles for images with 68-landmarks?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, face-recognition, matlab-cvst

I am trying to implement pose normalization for face images using piece-wise affine warping. I am using delaunayTriangulation to construct face mesh based on detected 68 landmarks for two images: one with frontal face and the other with non-frontal face. The resulted meshes do not have the same number of triangles and also have triangles that are different in direction and location.

Could anyone help please? Thanks.

```
% Construct mesh for frontal face image
filename1 = '0409';
img1 = imread([filename1 '.bmp']);
if(size(img1,3)==3)
   img1 = rgb2gray(img1);
end
figure, imshow(img1); hold on;
pts1 = load([filename1 '.mat']);    % Load 68-landmarks
DT1 = delaunayTriangulation(pts1.pts);
triplot(DT1,'cyan');

% Construct mesh for non-frontal face image 
filename2 = '0411';
img2 = imread([filename2 '.bmp']);
if(size(img2,3)==3)
   img2 = rgb2gray(img2);
end
figure, imshow(img2); hold on;
pts2 = load([filename2 '.mat']);     % Load 68-landmarks
DT2 = delaunayTriangulation(pts2.pts);
triplot(DT2,'cyan');
```

Comment: Delaunay triangulaties works as advertised. It seems that you need a different triangulation. What do you expect from your triangulation?

Comment: Thanks Cris. I want to implement pose normalization for face images using piece-wise affine warping. Firstly, I suppose the frontal image is a base image and the second image is input image. I want to warp the input image to the base image using piece-wise affine warping (PAW). PAW works on mapping each triangle in input image to the corresponding triangle in base image. How this happens if the number of triangles in the two images are different?

Comment: So you need to identify corresponding points, and define the same triangles in the two point sets. Delaunay might be useful in establishing triangles in the base model, but then you need to transfer those based on point correspondences to the other point set.

Comment: Correct PAW does this on each corresponding triangle pair. How to do that if the number of triangles are different?

Comment: You're thinking wrong. Your model has points and triangles between them. You find the same points on a new image, but you don't need to make new triangles there. You need to know which points match between the new set and the model. If points C,D and H on your model form a triangle, then so do the corresponding points on the new image. It's about matching up points, forget about the triangles.